# What is the proper way to create a build event with both double quotes and $ in files paths in VisualStudio using cmake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake

In my project I am trying to copy a directory of files into another directory through the post-build event command in visual studio.

I've come up with this command line code to use in the project `xcopy /Y /I /E "$(WorkingDirectory)/abra/kadabra" "$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)/kadabra"`

I would like to auto-generate this command from cmake and from what I understand the
`add_custom_command` method is what I should be using...

However when I try

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND xcopy /Y /I /E "$(WorkingDirectory)/abra/kadabra" "$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)/kadabra")
```

I get this as my commandline option in visual studio

```
    setlocal
xcopy /Y /I /E $(WorkingDirectory)/abra/kadabra $(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)/kadabra
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an answer, which is basically escaping the quotes. I turned this `"$(WorkingDirectory)/abra/kadabra" "$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)/kadabra")` into `\"$(WorkingDirectory)/abra/kadabra\" \"$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)/kadabra\")` However, I still get all of the extra setlocal and if %errorlevel% stuff which is not what I wanted. It doesn't however effect my project.